# Member name is the same as class during JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON payload that for reasons outside of my control contain a property (i.e. member) named exactly the same as its class name. Something like:

```
{ 
  ...,
   "Id": {
      "A" : "Hello",
      "B" : "World",
      ...
      "Id" : 1
   },
   ...
}
```

When I derive a class from this payload, I need something like this:

```
class Id{
   public string A, B;
   public int Id;
}
```

Obviously, the compiler complains with: *member names cannot be the same as enclosing type*

How can I rename the member (or the class for that effect), so Json.NET (the library I'm using to maker it easier) is able to "hydrate" payloads just by calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` ?

Answer (score 5):

Use a different name for property, and give a hint to json.net  how to deserialize that property...

```
public class Id
{
    public string A {get; set;}
    public string B {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int IdProp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonpropertyattribute.htm) attribute which allows you to specify the name of the source property while mapping to a destination property of a different name.

```
public class Id
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int ExtId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, I would appreciate your feedback.